# Using "ring someone up" correctly

Tags: gerunds, phrasal-verbs

There is expression "ring someone up". Would it be correct if I wrote the following:

> He kept ringing the hotel stubbornly, asking whether there were messages left for him.

Is "ring the hotel" used in a proper way?

Comment: To *ring* a hotel or anybody else simply means to make a phone call. To keep doing so means *repeatedly*. To add *stubbornly* doesn't affect the meaning although the context is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that statement is perfectly correct.
To "ring" someone is indeed, as Ronald mentioned, to (phone) "call" someone.
"He rings the hotel. He is ringing the hotel. He rang the hotel."
"I want to **ring up** the hotel" is also perfectly acceptable, even though admittedly it sounds a bit clumsy.